Failed to Build - Unable to read Google Service plist at path
My entire project was working fine until I updated Firebase to 10.27.00 & MacOS 14.5, I'm using Xcode 15.4. When trying to build the app now I get the following
Unable to read Google Service plist at path
find: dSYM_directory: No such file or directory

I have gone through the following steps.
Step 1)

Download google-service.plist from Firebase.
Add to project folder, check target.
Add to Target > Build Settings > Copy Bundle Resources

Errors:
Unable to read Google Service plist at path /Users/approot/Shared/GoogleService-Info.plist


find: dSYM_directory: No such file or directory


Sandbox: cp(38870) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/approot/Shared/GoogleService-Info.plist

Step 2) Ensure File Permissions:
Verify that the GoogleService-Info.plist file has the correct permissions.
chmod 644 /Users/approot/Shared/GoogleService-Info.plist

Step 3) Create a new "Run Script Phase" to copy the file
bash
Copy code
SRC="${SRCROOT}/Shared/GoogleService-Info.plist"
DEST="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"

echo "Source path: $SRC"
echo "Destination path: $DEST"

if [ -f "$SRC" ]; then
    echo "Copying $SRC to $DEST"
    cp "$SRC" "$DEST"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error copying file."
        exit 1
    fi
else
    echo "File not found: $SRC"
    exit 1
fi

Step 4) Check File System Access:
Ensure that Xcode has full disk access. This can sometimes resolve sandbox-related issues.
Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy tab.
Select Full Disk Access and make sure Xcode is added to the list of applications with full disk access.

Step 5) Check Derived Data:
Delete the derived data folder.
Example Run Script Phase with Debugging
Here’s an enhanced version of the script to include more detailed debugging information:
bash
Copy code
#!/bin/bash

SRC="${SRCROOT}/Shared/GoogleService-Info.plist"
DEST="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"

echo "Source path: $SRC"
echo "Destination path: $DEST"

if [ -f "$SRC" ]; then
    echo "File exists. Copying $SRC to $DEST"
    cp "$SRC" "$DEST"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error copying file."
        exit 1
    fi
else
    echo "File not found: $SRC"
    exit 1
fi

Step 6) Restart Xcode

Re-indexed Project
Closed Xcode
deleted derived data
reopened the project to allow
Reinstalled packaages
Reinstall Xcode
Restart MacOS
Jump out a window

I've repeated these steps 250+ times, the file is in the project, it has the target checked, I've added to bundle resources, it literally worked before updating macOS. I even have the previous iOS build uploaded to AppStoreConnect, we just needed latest version and upload MacOS app.

Open XCode go to runner select GoogleService-info select fullpath in ios/runner/GoogleService-info

